# How to import a module from a zip file which is encrypted

Tags: python, zip

I have a module which I've written, and it consists of several files, so I've packed it into a zip file and then I added the zip into the path variable:

```
mylib_zip_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
mylib_zip_path = os.path.join(mylib_zip_dir, "mylib.zip")
sys.path.insert(0, mylib_zip_path)
import mylib
```

I've been asked if I could encrypt the zip file but still use the module as I currently use it. I've seen ways for Python to extract an encrypted zip file, but can't figure out how I could still use it the way I currently do.

Is there a way add the zip file's password to my script so that it'll know how to decrypt and import the module? I'm aware that this goes against the open source nature of Python, but I would still like to know if and how I could achieve that.

Comment: And what would in your opinion be the advantage of doing that? It will not "secure" your source code.

Comment: @KlausD. It's not read proof I suppose, but it's meant to make it more difficult for simple users. Not an ideal solution in my opinion, but I was asked to look into it.

Comment: I don't want to get into an off-topic discussion here. I'll ask just one question you might answer to yourself: Aren't the simple users the one target group you don't need to protect the code from?

Comment: @KlausD. Fair point, it's more for the people with some knowledge that can't be bothered trying too hard. As a coworker put it, it's "hardening" and not truly protecting. We probably won't go with it, but I want to give it a bit of an effort.